# How to ensure the security of APIs which is open to front-end and other servers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, api

I am building a website. This site's front-end page needs to get/post data via `AJAX` from/to server, and the server provides the same APIs to other apps(private apps, not public, under the same 1st class domain).

For example, `POST /api/users` is used to create a new user. The site will provide a register page, which will use this API to register user(via `AJAX`). I want the other apps to also be able to use this API to register user.

In general, I use hashed string to authenticate the request from other apps. But I don't think that I can do the same thing for the front page.

I don't want to use two different APIs for front page and other apps separately. So how can I do this?

I am using Node.js and Express.

Comment: What do you mean by "other apps" ? Why are "other apps" different from the front-end page?

Comment: @Cristy Well, with external apps, you could then have CORS issues as well.

Comment: @Cristy For example, this site under the domain a.abc.com, it has a register page. Now there is another site under domain b.abc.com(yes, same 1st class domain), when a user register submit a register request, the b site actually posts the data to a site(server to server) to register. The b site is one of the 'other apps'.

Comment: @krillgar I didn't really understand the question. Does he already have an `API`? He says he uses "hashed string" for requests from other apps, why can't he use the same logic on requests coming from the front-end pages?

Comment: This is actually fairly broad I think. You're going to want to look into something like Oauth and OpenID Connect

Comment: @BrickYang All you have to do is to make the request cross-domain and set the corresponding CORS headers from the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's the same 1st class domain name, it is still considered a cross-origin request.

Comment: @Cristy You asked "why can't he use the same logic on requests coming from the front-end pages", because every one can see the code in front-end, and they will know the algorithm to make the secret string.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a combination of APIs. Login a user or creating a user should return a Session token. Then, every subsequent request should include that token. The other APIs on your server, should not allow requests without a user session token. So, when a requests comes in to eg: /app/data, the server looks up the session token (usually sent in a header) to verify the user exists and is logged in.

This typically works in a mobile app with website scenario because users will have to register via the website. Therefore, the registration API is restricted to the website by way of disallowing CORS for the registration API, but allowing CORS for all other APIs in your server. As long as they look up the Session token to verify it is valid, then I don't think there are too many security risks there.

A more advanced and secure approach would be to secure the API with OAuth 2. Since you own the server, it would be quite easy to register user via an OAuth 2 handshake from both website and mobile app.

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused here. Doesn't the CORS problem occur between front end and server end? What about server to server?

Comment: For server to server communication, you can validate the incoming requests using a Session Token. That way you know the server is logged in. You could also use CORS to block a server running on a different IP address. Typically servers run in the 10.0.0.0/24 range of IPs behind a firewall. But, you could only allow access from 10.0.1.33 using the CORS headers.

Comment: Servers that run on 10.0.0.0/24 will usually be set up to communicate without security like you would running tests on Localhost. However, this behavior is easy to modify.

Comment: Another server would be acting like a client when communicating with a server. However, CORS is more about protecting the user of a client from cross-origin requests. A client can easily ignore the CORS headers, and CORS isn't about blocking client requests on the server side. It's about blocking requests to a server on the client side. What Aaron Franco is essentially saying is to whitelist IPs/domains which isn't what CORS is about.

Comment: A server won't accept requests from a domain that isn't allowed in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header... which is very much about protecting a server from invalid Client attacks.

Comment: @AaronFranco That depends on the specific implementation of CORS, but you are essentially whitelisting IPs or domains in the end, and you don't need CORS for that. Furthermore, IPs/Domains can be spoofed. For true security, OAuth2 is going to be needed (or some similar auth protocol/spec)

Comment: @AaronFranco If I send the request from a server, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't seem work. I think it can only forbid the browser's Ajax request.

Comment: @BrickYang can you post the server code you are using?